# Accuracy of 'FV' function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Heres the scenario:

Investing £10 per month for 12 months (investing at the start of the month).
Annual equivalent rate of return 5%. Monthly = 5%/12= 0.4166667%

Now using the FV function this is what I typed:

```
=FV(0.00416666666666667,12,-10,0,1)
```

The answer is: £123.30

Now there are a few ways of doing this manually that I can think of (all similar but they get the same result).

This is one of them:

```
       A                      B                        c
Monthly start amount¦Monthly interest rate¦ Respective rows of A*B

10                  ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.041666667
20                  ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.083333333
30                  ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.125
40                  ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.166666667
50                  ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.208333333
60                  ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.25
70                  ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.291666667
80                  ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.333333333
90                  ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.375
100                 ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.416666667
110                 ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.458333333
120                 ¦ 0.004166667         ¦ 0.5


 Then add up all of column C + the last figure on column A (120) = 120 + 3.25 = £123.25
```

Which of course is different to the FV calculation. It doesn't really matter on small numbers like this, but if you are investing a lot more with a higher interest rate then the differences start to become noticable.

Now my question is - which one is right - if its the FV formula then where am I going wrong with the manual calculation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your challenge is that you're not taking compound interest into account....

Your first month will give you `0.04166` as you said, BUT the next month, you don't have only `$20` to invest, you technically have `$20.04166` and so forth...

When you take that into account, you get the value the `FV()` function would give you.

Sorry about the inaccurate currency symbol, but hope that makes sense.